# Apache Giraph/Hadoop: Iterating through custom ArrayWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, iterator, giraph, writable

I thought this would be simple to implement, but it's starting to be a pain.

I've got a ArrayWritable subclass like so:

```
public class VertexDistanceArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public VertexDistanceArrayWritable() {
        super(VertexDistanceWritable.class);
    }
    public VertexDistanceArrayWritable(VertexDistanceWritable[] v) {
        super(VertexDistanceWritable.class, v);
    }
}
```

And a Writable subclass like so:

```
public class VertexDistanceWritable implements Writable {

    //Implements write, readFields, and some custom functions that aren't used yet

}
```

In my Giraph compute function, Messages are VertexDistanceArrayWritable's.  I want to iterate through every VertexDistanceWritable every message (VertexDistanceArrayWritable).  Here is my compute function:

```
@Override
public void compute(Vertex<Text, MapWritable, FloatWritable> vertex,
    Iterable<VertexDistanceArrayWritable> messages) throws IOException {

    for(VertexDistanceArrayWritable message : messages) {
        for(VertexDistanceWritable distEntry : message) {
            //Do stuff with distEntry
        }
    }

    //do other stuff

    vertex.voteToHalt();
}
```

When I compile the code, I get this error:

```
for-each not applicable to expression type
    for(VertexDistanceWritable distEntry : message) {

  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    VertexDistanceArrayWritable
```

So now I have a problem. I want to iterate over the arrayWritable sub-class.

I've tried the following:

- Change that line to `for(VertexDistanceWritable distEntry : message.toArray())` which tells me that for-each not applicaable to type Object (required:  array or java.lang.Iterable, found:  Object).
- Change that line to `for(VertexDistanceWritable distEntry : message.get() )`, which gives me `error: incompatible types` -- `required:  VertexDistanceWritable, found: Writable`.  **This is the strangest problem -- VertexDistanceWritable extends Writable, shouldn't this work fine?**
- Writing my own custom "get_foo()" function for VertexDistanceWritable, which returns values as a VertexDistanceWritable[].  Of course, values is private, and has no getter function according to [the documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html#get()) other than get() which I'm already having problems with

I just want a way to iterate over my VertexDistanceArrayWritable class.  Is this even possible in Hadoop?  It has to be, right?  I should be able to iterate over a bunch of elements I made in an array, no?  It seems like pretty darn basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

After about 30 minutes of experimenting and googling, I found out a clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106146/read-values-wrapped-in-hadoop-arraywritable).  Sort of cheesy, but it seems to compile correctly.  Basically just use a Writable then cast it to my custom writable.

```
for(VertexDistanceArrayWritable message : messages) {
    for(Writable distWritable : message.get()) {
        vertexDistanceWritable distEntry = (VertexDistanceWritable) distWritable;
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

I haven't yet confirmed if it works correctly, I will update and confirm my answer when I can make sure it works.

edit: it works.  Might require a copy constructor since I had one for VertexDistanceWritable, but never checked that out.